# How to resize WorldWind Panel?

Tags: javafx, resize, worldwind

I want to put a `WorldWindowGLJPanel` into a Pane, and I want to **make it resizable**, but I can't, even when I call `resize` or `setSize` method.

Here's *what I'm doing* :

```
wwd = new WorldWindowGLJPanel();
wwd.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(300, 300));
wwd.setModel(new BasicModel()); 

swingNode = new SwingNode(); 
swingNode.setContent(wwd); 

wwdPane = new Pane();
wwdPane.getChildren().add(swingNode);
```

Then I use this `wwdPane` to display World Wind.

I want my `world wind panel` to have the size of the pane which contains it, and I want to make this `world wind panel` resizable.

I thought about give the size to my `world wind panel` of my `pane` with a `setSize(PaneDimenson)` and then **bind the size of my worldwindpanel with my pane** , but the `setSize` function *doesn't work*.

**EDIT** : I found an alternative solution by not using a pane, but directly the swingNode, the resize is now automatic. But if you want to use a pane there's still a problem, and you're force to use a group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setSize is working, try this code:

```
scene.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
   @Override public void changed( ObservableValue<? extends Number> o, Number b, Number a ) {
      Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            wwd.setSize((int)(a.intValue()*0.5), wwd.getHeight());
         }
      });
```

or with Java8

```
scene.widthProperty().addListener((o,b,a)->Platform.runLater(()->
   wwd.setSize((int)(a.intValue()*0.5), wwd.getHeight())));
```

But I couldn't make the resize work in my sample code, because the SwingNode somehow mess up the resizing, I think you should try the solution advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23642899/4711547).

Comment: The problem comes from the swingNode, but the solution in the other topic does not work for me ...

Comment: If I use a group the solution of the other topic work.

Comment: I'm glad that you solved it, I didn't have any other idea. This SwingNode feature is just for backward compatibility and I believe it is always risky to connect with a swing based library if you didn't write that library.