# Resize SwingNode in Pane

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, fxml

I'm fairly new to using JavaFX and I am looking to add a JPanel into a JavaFX Pane. The code I currently have works, however the panel is very small. I want to be able to resize it so it fits the JavaFX pane.

Code:

```
    // Add swing component to JFX
    final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();

    createAndSetSwingContent(swingNode);
    detailPane.getChildren().add(swingNode);
```

Create Swing content method:

```
 private void createAndSetSwingContent(final SwingNode swingNode) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //Create the  viewing pane.
            dataComponentDetailPane = new JEditorPane();
            dataComponentDetailPane.setEditable(false);
            dataDetailView = new JScrollPane(dataComponentDetailPane);

            // Create panel
            mainSwingPanel = new JPanel();
            mainSwingPanel.add(dataDetailView);
            swingNode.setContent(mainSwingPanel);
        }
    });
}
```

How do I fit the SwingNode/JPanel to fit the size of the JavaFX pane ?

I'm using FMXL to create the Java FX pane. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue than you and there's really a **problem between `Panel` and `SwingNode`**, I don't know exactly why but I have not find the way of using this 2 together.

Right now *I have 2 solutions* :

- You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350890/how-to-resize-swing-control-which-is-inside-swingnode-in-javafx8/23642899#23642899) and if you use `group` call : `setAutosizeChildren(false)` like said the solution.
- You can implement the `SwingNode` without using the JPanel, just put it in the `JavaFX Pane` you have, and it will automatically fits.

If this don't work, post a compilable code.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I was trying to re-use custom swing components I created in the panel so was really trying to be lazy, but I've just started re writing them in FX. Thanks again for your comments though !

Comment: It's better to avoid use of Swing in JavaFX, because SwingNode doesn't works fine with big application :)

Comment: Yeh I've found that out the hard way ! haha, Thanks :)

Comment: I am trying to convert an application that uses jgraphx (based on awt/swing). Any general solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem,  my solution is:

1. Use the AnchorPane pane:

---

```
 AnchorPane detailPane;
```

2. create your SwingNode (like you do):

---

```
createAndSetSwingContent(swingNode);;                       
// add the following code to make sure the swing node grows with the window.
AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(swingNode, 0d);
AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(swingNode, 0d);
AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(swingNode, 0d);
AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(swingNode, 0d);  

detailedPane.getChildren().add(swingNode); // Adding swing node
```